# why does terminal keeps displaying 'number of files 1'?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, gtk, nautilus

Please see this image:
[image]
[image]
The terminal always keeps displaying `number of files 1`. the frequency is about several minutes each. Restarting OS(to me it's centos) doesn't help because I've been seen it for months. Though it doesn't affect other processes, it harasses the terminal and I have to press CTRL+C to stop it tempararily, and I'm worried some background process is always in wrong state. Does it have anything to do with my command to dispaly gui folders needed at work?

```
nautilus -q &> /dev/null
nautilus dir1 dir2 .. dirn  &> /dev/null & 
#can prevent the 'number of files 1'.
```

I've googled the keyword 'number of files 1' but none of the results seem to be related to this question and so I'm wondering if others met the same issue before.
Could you give some suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue?

```
[root@localhost cp2vm]# whoami
root
[root@localhost cp2vm]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 22 21:09:27 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of `strings /usr/bin/nautilus`:
http://www.filedropper.com/stringsnautilus

`nautilus --version` output: GNOME nautilus 3.22.3

Comment: `strings $(which nautilus) | grep "number of files"`?

Comment: @ptomato it returns `number of files %d`, what can be implied?  I uploaded the whole output and updated question.

Comment: It means that yes, `number of files 1` is coming from nautilus, and therefore likely is related to your command to display GUI files.

Comment: It's most likely a leftover debug print in your version of nautilus. I searched the current nautilus codebase and didn't find it, but you may find it by going back and looking at the source code for the version of nautilus that your system has.

Comment: I also didn't find such string `number of files %d` in [source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/tree/3.22.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `nautilus &> /dev/null` to avoid nautilus polluting `stdout` and `stderr`. This way your terminal won't show those messages.

**Edit:**
To make it explicit, this should work in your script.

```
nautilus -q &> /dev/null              # Exits all nautilus instances, ignore output
nautilus dir1 dir2 dir3 &> /dev/null  # Runs nautilus, ignore output
```

I doubt the output redirection is useful for `nautilus -q`, but from your information it's hard to understand when and how often you call that script. So it might be in surplus, but won't harm.

Comment: thanks, I'll monitor several days before accepting as answer. More explanation of reason is appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately not work. my script is like this: `nautilus -q
nautilus some dirs & > /dev/null`

Comment: You must use `&>` with no space between both characters. That's a redirection of both `stdout` and `stderr`. See [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#IO-REDIRECTION).

Comment: still not work, `nautilus -q &> /dev/null
nautilus some dirs & &> /dev/null`

Comment: Please post your tries in your question, one command per line. Here the formatting makes it unclear how you are typing it, as line breaks are not shown.

Comment: hi, I created a shell script containing above commands. not typing every time.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it clearer, please check it works for you.

Comment: should I remove ending `&` which is for background process?

Comment: Makes no difference. Nautilus forks its process in the backroung already, so you can omit it.

Comment: thanks, i put the & at the very ending. and now no such message any more. by the way, can you tell me the **reason** of this message?

Comment: This is just some kind of debugging message forgotten by the developpers.